# How to return arrays from Rust functions without them being copied?

Tags: arrays, rust

I have a string of functions that generate arrays and return them up a call stack. Roughly the function signatures are:

```
fn solutions(...) -> [[u64; M]; N] {                         /* run iterator on lots of problem sets */ }
fn generate_solutions(...) -> impl Iterator<Item=[u64; M]> { /* call find_solution on different problem sets */ }
fn find_solution(...) -> [u64; M] {                          /* call validate_candidate with different candidates to find solution */ }
fn validate_candidate(...) -> Option<[u64; M]> { 
    let mut table = [0; M];
    // do compute intensive work
    if works { Some(table) } else { None }
 }
```

My understanding was that Rust will not actually *copy* the arrays up the call stack but optimize the copy away.

But this isn't what I see. When I switch to `Vec`, I see 20x speed improvement with the only change being `[u64;M]` to `Vec<u64>`. So, it is totally copying the arrays over and over.

So why array and not `Vec`, everyone always asks. Embedded environment. `no_std`.

How to encourage Rust to optimize these array copies away?

Comment: First question: Did you turn on all optimizations before doing your benchmark? If you ran your comparisons in `debug` mode, then it's a meaningless test. Second question: Is aggressive inlining an option for you? It's possible you could have Rust just inline the function calls and never even have to deal with return values at all, depending on the size of the functions.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Hi, yes, I have optimizations on. Without them on, my code would never complete :)  I'm open all all optimizations, but preferably they'd be compiler switches instead of me combining all the code into a single monolithic function.

Comment: You can `#[inline(always)]`.

Comment: @Ana Inlining is an attribute applied to functions (Chayim showed the syntax). Internally, Rust piles all of your functions into one thing, but you don't have to do it in the code; it's a compiler trick.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I added the inline attribute to all the functions. No difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, *guaranteed* lack of copies is currently an unsolved problem in Rust. To get the characteristics you want, you will need to explicitly pass in storage it should be written into (the “out parameter” pattern):

```rust
fn solutions(..., out: &mut [[u64; M]; N]) {...}
fn find_solution(..., out: &mut [u64; M]) {...}
fn validate_candidate(table: &mut [u64; M]) -> bool { 
    // write into table
    works
}
```

Thus you will also have to find some alternative to `Iterator` for `generate_solutions` (since using `Iterator` implies that all the results *can* exist at once without overwriting each other).

Comment: I considered this. Was hoping to return the array but this will have to do. Thanks.